# Relative anomalies in multiple multivariate times series with different lengths?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, multivariate-analysis, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a set of time series, highly correlated (similar peaks and trend). I'm going to find relative anomalies, e.g. say there are 20 times series. At a snapshot date, all values increase, but one decrease, I want to label that one as anomaly, or say one day all increases, but one increases more significantly, I want to label that as an anomaly.
The example was kind of univariate, but I have a few variables, although they are correlated.

any suggestion on methods? any reference?

Second question is how to measure performance of the model?

Comment: See https://prital.netlify.app/publication/stray/

Comment: Measure how much they correlate over an appropriate window of time, and use the correlation score as a feature for an anomaly detector